# Python - Tkinter with labels & photos

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

I am making a program that gives you information and a picture about a planet/star. I am using tkinter to do so.

Here is the code that the problem arises around:

```
sunPic = r'sun.gif'
mercPic = r'merc.gif'


buttonFrame = Frame(root)
buttonFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

textFrame = Frame(root)
textFrame.pack(side=TOP)


def sunInfo():

    sunImage = PhotoImage(file=sunPic)
    img1 = Label(textFrame, image = sunImage)
    img1.image = sunImage
    img1.pack()


def mercInfo():

    mercImage = PhotoImage(file=mercPic)
    img1.configure(image = mercImage)
    img1.image = mercImage
    img1.pack()

sun = Button(buttonFrame, text="THE SUN",command=sunInfo)
sun.pack(side=TOP)

mercury = Button(buttonFrame, text="MERCURY",command=mercInfo)
mercury.pack(side=TOP)
```

When you press a button, it is supposed to change images. So say if I press THE SUN button, a pic of the sun would appear, and then I press the MERCURY button, a picture of mercury would replace the pic of the sun.

This doesn't work, however. When I click on the mercury button it comes up with this error:

```
img1.configure(image = mercImage)
NameError: global name 'img1' is not defined
```

Also, if I press THE SUN button several times, several images of the sun show up! I do not want this.

What I want to do in this program:

- Create buttons with the planets names on.
- Allow the user to press those buttons
- A PICTURE and some INFORMATION on that planet show up
- If the user presses another button, the PICTURE and INFORMATION is replaced by the new PLANETS information and picture.

This is a project I need to finish by tonight. I have little tkinter experience, and I need help.

Thank you.

ALSO:

Here is the full code that I am working on:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()



root.geometry('1024x768+200+200') # makes window (x,y+top left corner right + top left corner down)
root.title("Planetary Information") # creates title for window

sunPic = r'sun.gif'
mercPic = r'merc.gif'


buttonFrame = Frame(root)
buttonFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

textFrame = Frame(root)
textFrame.pack(side=TOP)


def sunInfo():

    sunImage = PhotoImage(file=sunPic)
    img1 = Label(textFrame)
    img1.configure(image = sunImage)
    img1.image = sunImage
    img1.pack()


def mercInfo():

    mercImage = PhotoImage(file=mercPic)
    img1.configure(image = mercImage)
    img1.image = mercImage
    img1.pack()




sun = Button(buttonFrame, text="THE SUN",command=sunInfo)
sun.pack(side=TOP)

mercury = Button(buttonFrame, text="MERCURY",command=mercInfo)
mercury.pack(side=TOP)

venus = Button(buttonFrame, text="VENUS")
venus.pack(side=TOP)

earth = Button(buttonFrame, text="EARTH")
earth.pack(side=TOP)

mars = Button(buttonFrame, text="MARS")
mars.pack(side=TOP)

jupiter = Button(buttonFrame, text="JUPITER")
jupiter.pack(side=TOP)

saturn = Button(buttonFrame, text="SATURN")
saturn.pack(side=TOP)

uranus = Button(buttonFrame, text="URANUS")
uranus.pack(side=TOP)

neptune = Button(buttonFrame, text="NEPTUNE")
neptune.pack(side=TOP)

root.mainloop() #
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because of the [variable scope](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). To put it simply: the variable `img1` belongs to the function `suninfo()`, so when any other function tries to access it, it can't, so the traceback tells you:

```
NameError: global name 'img1' is not defined
```

The best fix would be to put your code inside a class, but the quickest fix would be to make `img1` outside the function, then update it as required:

```
buttonFrame = Frame(root)
buttonFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

textFrame = Frame(root)
textFrame.pack(side=TOP)

img1 = Label(textFrame) #Create img1 outside the function
img1.pack()

def sunInfo():
    sunImage = PhotoImage(file=sunPic)
    img1.pack_forget()                 #Drop previous img1 picture
    img1.configure(image = sunImage)
    img1.image = sunImage
    img1.pack()                        #Re-pack as new image

def mercInfo():
    mercImage = PhotoImage(file=mercPic)
    img1.pack_forget()
    img1.configure(image = mercImage)
    img1.image = mercImage
    img1.pack()

sun = Button(buttonFrame, text="THE SUN",command=sunInfo)
sun.pack(side=TOP)

mercury = Button(buttonFrame, text="MERCURY",command=mercInfo)
mercury.pack(side=TOP)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the picture isn't changing is because you need to update the widget. This can also be accomplished by the `.place()` method. Place the images on the same coordinates and it will change.

The reason the sun picture is showing several times is because of the `.pack()` method. The pack method packs the widget, automatically. You need to either create a update function or use the `.place()` method as said above.

Finally, when you press the mercury button, img1 isn't defined because it is not defined. You can create a `global` and put the global in the sun function and the mercury function.

The easiest way to refresh widgets is using the `.grid()` method and when you want to refresh the widget, use `.grid_forget()`.

You should read up on [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) and learn about the widgets you use.